# How do you find the heat capacity of a calorimeter?

Tags: thermodynamics, free-energy

My instructor gave me the formula:
$$C_\mathrm{cal} = \frac{C_\mathrm{bomb}}{\text{steel}+C_\mathrm{water}}$$
I know that the heat capacity for water is $4.184~\mathrm{J\,g^{-1}\,^\circ C^{-1}}$ and I calculated the value for $C_\mathrm{bomb}$, which is $356.7555~\mathrm{J\,g^{-1}\,^\circ C^{-1}}$. The part I don't understand is where it says steel. Is “steel” the same as “$C_\mathrm{bomb}$”?

Comment: You have this so discombobulated I can't tell what you are trying to do. Basically if $\mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{t}}$ is the total heat capacity for the system , $\mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{w}}$ is the heat capacity of the water, and $\mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{cal}}$ is then heat capacity of the calorimeter, then $$\mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{t}} = \mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{w}} + \mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{cal}}$$ so in order to raise the whole system by 1 degree C you have to supply enough heat to raise the water 1 degree and the calorimeter 1 degree.

Comment: Thus $$\mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{t}} \Delta \mathrm{T}= (\mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{w}} + \mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{cal}}) \Delta \mathrm{T}$$

Comment: If $\mathrm{c}_\mathrm{w}$  is the specific heat of water, 4.184 J/g⋅°C, and $\mathrm{g}_\mathrm{w}$ is the mass of the wtaer, then $$\mathrm{C}_\mathrm{w} = \mathrm{c}_\mathrm{w}\mathrm{g}_\mathrm{w}$$

Comment: What are $C_{cal}$, $C_{bomb}$ and $C_{water}$ supposed to be? If they are heat capacities, the formula is wrong.